# ListContourPlot - request for clarification, why do the derived regions differ, and how did I misuse it?

Tags: plotting

### Question

I have generated two data sets using `Outer` and `Subdivide` commands. Both use similar boundaries except the second dataset uses a higher bound for the 'y' axes. Now, I have decided to plot the two datasets using a `ListContourPlot` and overlay a set of gridlines to visualize a region of interest. I have expected both regions to look the same. However, this wasn't the case. I have also noticed inconsistency in the isopleths. For example, I would expect ~ 10^6 * .4 to be in green area. Instead, it is way above isopleth visualizing 500k$. I am sure I have misused the function in some way, and I would appreciate if somebody could shed some light on the subject.

Please note, I did manage to fix the issue by increasing the amount of elements generated by the `Subdivide` command from 4 to 100. Put in a Log10 scale using the new data, the regions also retained similarity. However, messing around with the `Subdivide` did affect the isopleths and the region of interest making them look different.

### Plots

[image]

### Code

```
data1 = Outer[{#1, #2, #1*#2} &, Subdivide[.02, 1, 4], Subdivide[10^4, 10^7, 4]] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
data2 = Outer[{#1, #2, #1*#2} &, Subdivide[.02, 1, 4], Subdivide[10^4, 2*10^7, 4]] // Flatten[#, 1] &;

colors2 = {"#a3d977", "#ffeca9", "#ffdf71" , "#ff8f80"};

x = ListContourPlot[
   (* Data Specification *)
   data1
   
   (* General Configuration *)
   , Frame -> True
   , ImageSize -> Medium
   , PlotRangeClipping -> False
   , ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log10"}
   
   (* Contour Configuration *)
   , Contours -> {500000, 1200000, 2200000}
   , ContourShading -> (RGBColor /@ colors2)
   , ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed, Black}}
   
   (* Annotation *)
   , PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]
   
   (* Region Configuration *)
   , GridLines -> {{.2, .4}, {10^6, 5*10^6}}
   , GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black]
   ];

y = ListContourPlot[
   (* Data Specification *)
   data2
   
   (* General Configuration *)
   , Frame -> True
   , ImageSize -> Medium
   , PlotRangeClipping -> False
   , ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log10"}
   
   (* Contour Configuration *)
   , Contours -> {500000, 1200000, 2200000}
   , ContourShading -> (RGBColor /@ colors2)
   , ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Dashed, Black}}
   
   (* Annotation *)
   , PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]
   
   (* Region Configuration *)
   , GridLines -> {{.2, .4}, {10^6, 5*10^6}}
   , GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black]
   ];

Grid @ {{
   Row @ {x, y}
   }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subdivisions are far too coarse to fairly represent features on the vast numerical ranges involved, so features are missed / misplaced. Try with finer-pitched subdivisions:

```
data2 = Outer[
          {#1, #2, #1*#2} &, 
          Subdivide[.02, 1, 40], Subdivide[10^4, 2*10^7, 40]
        ] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
```

[image: density plots from finer subdivisions]

Comment: In essence, this is the solution.

I also have increased the number of elements produced by the `Subdivide`, and it fixed the problem. However, there must be something fundamental to the emerging issue. How do you select the appropriate numerical range?